Getting duplicate Google Ads data in Big Query
I am getting duplicate data in my Big Query tables from Google Ads.
I can look at the tables and see rows with the exact same data. Furthermore when I aggregate the data to see total cost of campaigns, it is double what is shown in the Google Ads platform.
I followed the guide for the data transfer and didn't do anything outside the standard set up. I did do a backfill to get data for the entire month because it originally only imported data for the previous week. I also set the date range on the backfill to not include the week of data already imported. And there are duplicates for everyday of the month.
Has anyone experiences this and know why it is making duplicate entries and if so how do I get rid of the duplicates?

It's likely due to the day partitioning.
See here for more details: BigQuery Google Ads Transfer - Duplicate data
